# mongo db -- time query along with geolocation query

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-design, scale, geospatial

I need to do a geo-spatial query that is filtered by time (past 5 hrs). Thinking of doing the following, but not sure what will yield in the fastest query:

1. Migrate old data (older than 5 hours) to Archive table (runs in background periodically)
2. Geo-spatial query with time-box (query objects within a time frame)

   - think this one might be computationally expensive at scale ?
3. Geo-spatial query and filter results (drop all data less older than time constraint)

Really thinking about how this will work at a large scale. 
Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried? There is nothing wrong with using other query conditions along with a geospatial operator such as `$near`. So it's unclear what you are asking without showing what you have tried, and against what data to an intended result.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to see which approach would yield better results at scale. I know traditionally, NoSQL databases suffer when adding additional query operators. But MongoDB might be better at this... Just wanted to get people's opinions.

Comment: Which is exactly why a close vote exists on your question. With likely more to follow. Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) from the help center, which basically points to "opinions" are not really useful as a resource. You might as well ask *"Do you like Coke or Pepsi?"* I prefer Coke, but it's about as useful information as anyone's "opinion" on this topic. You might take note that "more reputable" users here will not offer an opinionated response here. So that also accounts for the usefulness of any answer you receive.